# Throw connection error at front end php

Tags: php

so I am a php beginner and i was making a login app with server and client side validation .I want to throw an error to the login page when the password is wrong after matching it with db or if email is not unique ..well something like that.
Thank you

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @u_mulder so i want to put error like "Wrong password" and "Email already exists" below thier respective fields in thier forms after checking the mysql db

Answer (score 0):

To display authentication error after checking from DB you need to use ajax

```
var username = "....";
var password = "....";
$.ajax({
    url: "/login",
    method: "POST",
    data:{username,password}
}).done(function(data) {
    if(data.success){
        $("#msg").html("Success");
    }else{
        $("#msg").html(data.err_msg);
    }
});
```

In php files

```
<?php
    function checkAuthentication(){
        $errormsg = "";
        $result = true;
        try {
            //your data and query to check 'username' and 'password'
            if(!$password_match){
                $result = false;
                $errormsg = 'Invalid credential';
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $result = false;
            $errormsg = 'Database error! ' . $exception->getMessage();
        }
        //return json data
        return json_encode(["success"=>$result,"err_msg"=>$errormsg]);
    }
?>
```

There are much more things to do but you can think this way to start

Comment: Thank you i will try this @user2486